# Extracting even / odd part of summation trick

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

Given a function $f(x)$, we know its even part is given as $\frac{f(x) + f(-x)}{2}$ and its odd part is given by $\frac{f(x) - f(-x)}{2}$.

Consider a discrete sequence given by $a_j$ for $j \geq 1$, then the sum of the terms in the sequence till $n$ terms is given as

$$ S= \sum_j^n a_j$$

Suppose I wanted to get the sum of the even terms in the above expression; then

$$ S_{odd}= \sum_j^n \frac{ a_{-j} + a_j}{2}$$

and, for odd,
$$ S_{odd} = \sum_j^n \frac{a_j - a_{-j} }{2}$$

But wait, our sequence was defined for $ j \geq 1$... Well, here's the thing:  $a_j$ is some function of $j$, extending the domain to negative integers and evaluating the function gives the right answer... but I can't understand why the continuous function trick extended to here.

Examples:

Sum of first n numbers given as $ \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, sum of first $n$ odds will be given as: $ \frac{n(n+1)}{2} -\frac{n(1-n)}{2}$

---

My attempt at finding an exact connection: To the discrete sequence $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ , we can associate a function $f(x)=\frac{x(x+1)}{2}$ and we can think of the summation as summing this function at several different input points i.e:

$$ S= \sum_j^n a_j \to \sum_k^n f(x+k)$$

Then we apply the even odd decomposition and return back to the sequence world.

My question: Does there exist an association for every sequence with a function? If not, what is the criterion for an association to exist?

Comment: You seem to be mixing even and odd functions with even and odd integers.  $x^2$ is an even function despite $3^2=9$ being odd, while $x^3$ is an odd function despite $2^3=8$ being even

Comment: How does that “trick” give “the right answer”? $\frac{n(n+1)}{2} -\frac{n(1-n)}{2} = n^2$ and $\frac{n(n+1)}{2} +\frac{n(1-n)}{2} = n$ are not the sum of the first $n$ odd or even integers. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Martin R the odd result is correct.

Comment: Ah stupid mistake on my part @MartinR

Comment: Now I realize another blunder the odd result should have had a half

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different approach yields the sum of the even terms:
$$S_{\text{even}}=\sum_j a_{2j} = \sum_j \frac{1+(-1)^j}{2}a_j$$

Similarly, the sum of the odd terms is
$$S_{\text{odd}}=\sum_j a_{2j-1} = \sum_j \frac{1-(-1)^j}{2}a_j$$

Answer (score 2):

The definition of "even" and "odd" used in the function definition mean that for an "even" function $g, g(x)=g(-x)$ for any $x$, and for an "odd" function $h, h(x)=-h(-x)$: the definitions are unrelated to the divisibility by 2 of any numbers.

So how are the discrete sequences related? Well, sorry to burst your bubble, but they aren't. Your formula for odds working is a coincedence, and it doesn't work for evens (it evaluates to $n$, which is not the sum of the first $n$ even numbers)